# Why can we express a plane as a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d

The plane equation is given as:

$\vec r = \vec r_0 + \lambda \vec a + \mu \vec b$

I understand that we can express line as a vector (although I'm not totally clear on that concept either), but what I really don't understand is how can a vector represent a plane?

I understand that we can represent any point on the plane by choosing the right $\lambda$ and $\mu$ (then we "walk around the plane), but what does $\vec r_0$ have to do with any of this? And again, how can a vector respresent an entire plane?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What to you mean by a vector "representing the entire plane"? In your parametric equation, $r_0$ simply tells you where the zero point of the $\lambda$-$\mu$ coordinate system for your plane is. (And thereby it tells you which of the many parallel planes with the same orientation you're speaking of).

Comment: There are *two* vectors, not one. This makes a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line can be described by

$$\vec r = \vec r_0 + \lambda \vec a$$ and you get *all* the points (an infinity of them) along the line by varying $\lambda$. In particular, with $\lambda=0$ you see that the line is through $\vec r_0$. The line is parallel to $\vec a$.

Similarly a plane can be described by

$$\vec r = \vec r_0 + \lambda \vec a+ \mu \vec b$$ and you get *all* the points  (a double infinity of them) on the plane by varying $\lambda$ and $\mu$. In particular, with $\lambda=\mu=0$ you see that the plane is through $\vec r_0$. The plane is parallel to both vectors $\vec a,\vec b$.